# Visual Studio - Code working on Release but not on Debug (C++)

Tags: c++, release, destructor

So the objective of my code is to have a string as an input, convert it to postfix, and attach each postfix character to a linked list.

**When I run my code on Release it works perfectly well, but when I run it on Debug it has the following error: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
temp was 0xDDDDDDDD on the print function of LinkedList**

[Error Message on my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fa6Z.png)

So this is my main method

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    LinkedList list1 = postfix("a*b+c/d-e");
    list1.print();
};
```

And this is my postfix function

```
LinkedList postfix(string input) {
    // Declare a stack with the capacity of 100 (it is just a large number)
    Stack<char> myStack(100);
    LinkedList returnList;

    // The for loop check the charactors in the infix expressing
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        // If the charactor is an operand, we attach it to the LinkedList
        if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') {
            returnList.attach(input[i]);
        }

        // If the operator is an open paranthesis, we push it into the stack
        else if (input[i] == '(') {
            myStack.Push(input[i]);
        }
        else if (input[i] == ')') {
            // If the stack is empty, it means there is no open paranthesis. It is an error, so we
            // terminate the program
            if (myStack.IsEmpty()) exit(0);
            char topOP;
            myStack.Pop(topOP);
            // We keep pop the operators in the stack and attach them into the output Postfix string        
            while (topOP != '(') {
                returnList.attach(topOP);
                myStack.Pop(topOP);
                // If we cannot find close parenthesis and the stack is empty, it is an error.
                if (myStack.IsEmpty()) exit(0);
            }
        }
        // If the charactor is an operator
        else {
            // Get the priority number of the incoming operator
            int p = priority(input[i]);
            // If the operator is not supported, we terminate the program
            if (p == -1) exit(1);

            // If there is no operator in the stack to compare, we just push the incoming
            // operator into the stack
            if (myStack.IsEmpty()) {
                myStack.Push(input[i]);
            }
            else {
                //we get the top operator
                char topOP = myStack.Top();

                //If the priority of the incoming operator is greater than the priority of the top operator
                //we push it to the stack
                if (p > priority(topOP)) {

                    myStack.Push(input[i]);
                }
                //if the priority of the incoming operator is less than or equal to the priority of the top operator
                else {
                    //we traverse through the stack until its is empty or...
                    //the priority of incoming operator is less than the current operator
                    while (!myStack.IsEmpty() && p <= priority(topOP) ) {
                        myStack.Pop(topOP);
                        returnList.attach(topOP);
                        if (myStack.IsEmpty()) { break; }
                        topOP = myStack.Top();
                    }
                    //we push the the incoming operator when the loop finished 
                    myStack.Push(input[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // We attach the operators remainding in the stack to the linked list
    while (!myStack.IsEmpty()) {
        char topOP;
        myStack.Pop(topOP);
        returnList.attach(topOP);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

**While debugging I've noticed where my error was**

On the postfix function, the variable returnList, was perfectly fine when it returned, and then the LinkedList destructor executed to destroy returnList

In my main function I equalized the variable list1 to the function postfix (which is a return by value).
While debugging, I've noticed that list1 ended with tons of garbage values, which I didn't understand because returnList (inside my postfix function) ended completely well

And as it is a return by value, a copy of returnList was made and then it was assigned to list1, and after that the destructor destroyed returnList (when the function ended)

Here is my LinkedList class

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    // In the beginning, the linked list is empty, so we set first to NULL
    LinkedList() {
        first = last = NULL;
    }

    // We return the memory of all nodes in the linked list back to the system
    ~LinkedList() {
        Node* temp = first;
        while (temp) {
            Node* prev = temp;
            temp = temp->link;
            delete prev;
        }
    }

    // If first is pointing to NULL, it implies the linked list is empty
    bool IsEmpty() { ... }


    // This function attaches a new element to the end of the linked list
    void attach(char newData) { ... }

    void print() {
        Node* temp = first;

        while (temp) {
            if (temp == last) {
                cout << temp->data << endl;
                temp = temp->link;
            }
            else {
                cout << temp->data << " -> ";
                temp = temp->link;
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

private:
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
};
```

And here is the Node Class

```
// This is the node of the linked list
class Node {
private:
    char data;
    // A poiter to the next node
    Node* link;
    // The class LinkedList will access the data in the class Node, so we declare
    // the class LinkedList as a friend class   
    friend class LinkedList;
};
```

**So why is this error occurring? And why is only occurring on Debug, but not on Release**

**Any help is appreciated**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Your code violates [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You should define copy constructor and assignment operator of `LinkedList` to copy the list, not just copy pointer values.

Comment: You return `LinkedList` by value, so it's being copied. But it doesn't have a user-defined copy constructor, so the copy uses the implicitly-defined one, that simply copies over `first` and `last` pointers. So you end up with two instances of `LinkedList`, each holding the same pointers, and each believing it owns them. When the first one is destroyed, it deallocates all the nodes, leaving the second one holding dangling pointers. Then that second instance tries to use now-dangling pointers, and crashes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks man! And do you know why it works on release but not on debug?

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks man! And do you know why it works on release but not on debug?

Comment: @EnzoDeFilippis It is not "working" in Release mode.  Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.  Change compiler options, or make your program more sophisticated, and you may get weird results in other places.  There is little point trying to figure out why bad code "works".

Comment: Also, `if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z')` -- this is not the correct way to check if a character is a lower case character.  There are systems out there where alphabetic characters are not contiguous.  There is a function called [islower()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) that checks if a character is lower case, and you should be using that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just wanted to understand what's like the difference between the debug and release version. But still, I've already corrected my code. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie for that tip!! But I was checking if it was a letter. I'll use isalpha()

Comment: @Enzo: Why only crash in debug mode? debug into it the code: the nodes were probably already destroyed somewhere else, and the memory was taken by someone else. But in release mode, that piece of memory has not been taken by another thing